# JavaFX mouse events not triggering in portions of area nesting a smaller canvas control

Tags: javafx-11

The code below has a main area and a smaller, overridden `Canvas` named `CenterArea` colored in red. Mouse events are not triggering when the mouse is located beyond the bottom or right edges of the `CenterArea`, even though still plainly within the main area.

To demonstrate, I've put a `.setOnMouseMoved` method in both the main "root" element and in the `CenterObject`. When the mouse is over the `CenterObject`, we get notifications from both as expected since the event is not consumed.

Why doesn't the method trigger for the main root area when the mouse is below or to the right of the `CenterObject`?

Is this a known bug or am I misunderstanding something?

The code below was executed with javafx-sdk-14.0.1 downloaded from gluon, running along with openjdk 11.0.1. I get the same behavior with both my Windows 10 and my Ubuntu 18.04 system.

```
public class MouseMoveTest extends Application
{         
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        Group root = new Group(); 
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 200, Color.DARKGREY);       

        root.setOnMouseMoved(e -> System.out.println("main mouse move"));

        CenterArea centerArea = new CenterArea(300, 100);
        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setPadding(new Insets(50, 0, 0, 100));           
        grid.add(centerArea, 0, 0);

        centerArea.setFocusTraversable(true);
        root.getChildren().add(grid);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();       
    }
}

class CenterArea extends Canvas {
    private GraphicsContext gc;

    public CenterArea(double arg1, double arg2)
    {
        super(arg1, arg2);
        gc = getGraphicsContext2D();
        gc.setFill(Color.RED);
        gc.fillRect(0, 0, arg1, arg2);

        setOnMouseMoved( e -> System.out.println("center mouse move"));
    }
}
```

EDIT 1:
The following code line has been added to the `start` method.

```
grid.setOnMouseMoved( e -> System.out.println("grid mouse move"));
```

There has been no code added to consume mouse events. Thus the mouse event freely bubbles up from `CenterArea` to `Grid` to `root`, AFAIK.

The result are similar to before the grid mouse event was added. Maybe the following will help disambiguate. Suppose we divide the screen into 9 areas.

- 0,0 holding root(left,top), messages observed: root, grid
- 1,0 holding root(middle,top), messages observed: root, grid
- 2,0 holding root(right,top), messages observed: NONE
- 0,1 holding root(left,middle), messages observed: root, grid
- 1,1 holding CenterArea(middle,middle), messages observed:
  root, grid, center
- 2,1 holding root(right,middle), messages observed: NONE
- 0,2 holding root(left,bottom), messages observed: NONE
- 1,2 holding root(middle,bottom,), messages observed: NONE
- 2,2 holding root(right,bottom), messages observed: NONE

Comment: Cause of gridpane. It is over the root node and intercept mouse move event, i think. If you put onmousemove to gridpane you should see how event works.

Comment: Interesting idea. I added code to see if the Grid was also sensing the mouse. No changes in results though. See notes in section "EDIT".

Comment: Well. I tried your code. If you add some background you'll see how it is positioned. Cause Group is only a container for other nodes it doesn't fire mouse event on area where there is no any elements. You can try to change Group to StackPane(for example) and check how it works

Comment: Now that makes sense about Group only firing where there are elements. Didn't think of that but it accounts for the behavior. Thank you! Will experiment tomorrow on this.